# dynamically change facebook og image in a fancybox share button

Tags: facebook, image, dynamic, share, fancybox-2

**The goal :**

I would like to have a share button in my fancybox that share the image I'm looking at with the correct image name in the Facebook sharer. I would like that when a user click on this in Facebook, he arrives on an opened Fancybox with the correct image.

**The problem :**

I have a gallery with Jquery FancyBox (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/). I added a share button with the code I find in this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/G5TC3/).
My share button works, but get the meta og from the site and I want to have the og:image from the image I'm looking at.

```
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        if (this.title) {

            // Add FaceBook like button
            this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:110px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
        }
    },
    helpers : {
        title : {
            type: 'inside'
        }
    }  
});
```

For the user who clicks on my link and arrives on an opened Facybox with the correct image I have no idea how to do that and if it's possible.

**What I know:** 

I know that I have to have uniques URL for each images and I think I have it. ex from my site:
www.myURL.com/images/gallery/myimages_1.jpg
www.myURL.com/images/gallery/myimages_2.jpg

Is it correct?

I think I have to change the "this.href" in the sharer by the image url. First is it correct? And second (sorry I'm new in javascript) how can I do that?

I hope somebody could help me. Sorry for my English I'm trying to write my best English :)
If you need more information please do not hesitate.

Thanks

[EDIT]:

I add this script on the gallery page

```
$(function()
{
    $('.thumbs').click(function()
    {
        $tempImgName = $(this).attr('id');
        $tempUrl = this.href + '/images/thumbs/' + $tempImgName;
        $meta = document.getElementById('facebook');
        $meta.setAttribute("content",$tempUrl);
    });
});
```

So when I click on a thumbsnail (with the class .thumbs) I get the image URL and I change the meta (with the facebook Id). It works but I think Facebook check the meta when the page load so how can I force Facebook to recheck my meta to take the good thumbs to share?

Comment: not yet I didn't understand the first answer sorry.

Answer (score 0):

og:image cannot change by url. You need to give different share urls for different images.

For example :-

www.myURL.com/?pic=img1

www.myURL.com/?pic=img2 etc.

And a server side language ( like php ) can read the "pic" GET argument and change the og:image.

Comment: Ok I think I have a different URL for each images. I just don't know how to GET the image url in PHP.

I have seen something like this in a code but I don't understand how to relate the "i" (I don't know where it comes from) with an url

http://myURL.com/pics/".$_GET['i'];

Can you explain me briefly. Thx a lot!

Comment: Ah, then here is what you should do 

`'<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.myURL.com/images/gallery/myimages'.$_GET['i'].'" />';`


And the share url should be www.myURL.com/?i=1 or i=2 etc.

Comment: I have edited my question. Now I change the meta tag when I click on a thumbs but I don't know how to force Facebook to recheck my meta. Is it possible? Thx

Comment: Changing meta in js wont work. As facebook is scraping you page from a non browser environment.

Comment: Ok so I think dynamically changing de og image of Facebook on a click is impossible.

Comment: From javascript yes, its impossible. From Server end however its still possible

Comment: Yes but I don't understand how.
I have my images in a folder myrul.com/images/thumbs, I want the correct image when I click on share in the Fancybox.

Can you make a new answer with a piece of code to explain how to get the correct image and give it to the Facebook sharer when I click on the Share button. Thx